# Cannot connect my mobile to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: usb

Ubuntu Version 17.04 (64 bit)
Mobile: Moto G4 (Plus) Android 7.0
When I connect my mobile to the laptop, and select Transfer File option on mobile, the mobile does not show.
If I give the lsusb command, it shows in the list.

A few weeks ago I was able to connect the mobile to the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the terminal with Ctrl + Alt + T.
2. Do `sudo apt-get install adb`.
3. After installation, do `adb devices`. You should allow USB debugging in your device.
4. Then you can use commands `adb push local_folder remote_folder` to push files into your phone or `adb pull remote_folder local_folder` to pull files from your phone.